# Django template not executing js function

Tags: javascript, django, templates, function, parameters

I have  a django template that looks like this:

```
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<!--<script src="c:/src/project/scraper/collegedata/templates/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="chart1" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>


    <script>
       show_graph("{{ chart_type }}", {{ series_names }}, {{ data }}, {{ answer }});
    </script>

    <form action="start">
        <input type="submit" value="Back to Questions" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

where show_graph is a function in chart.js. However, pycharm gives me one of two errors, either:
unresolved function or method show_graph(), or
invalid number of parameters passed: expected 4

and the function is clearly not being called.

I'm a little confused as to whether or not I can even pass template vars to a js function at all...

Does anyone have any insight?

EDIT:

this generates

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<!--<script src="c:/src/project/scraper/collegedata/templates/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="/static/js/chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="chart1" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>


    <script>
       show_graph("pie", [&lt;ResponseOption: puddentane&gt;, &lt;ResponseOption: down the lane&gt;], [1, 0], 0);
    </script>

    <form action="start">
        <input value="Back to Questions" type="submit">
    </form>

</body></html>
```

where chart.js looks like (values temporarily hardcoded for troubleshooting, and it should be mentioned that $.plot also gives an unresolved function error):

```
function show_graph(charttype, series_names, data, answer_index){

    var data = [2000, 50, 400, 200, 5000];

    var data3 = [
    { label: "my cat",  data: 10, color: 'rgb(85, 96, 42)'},
    { label: "my friends",  data: 20, color: 'rgb(105, 118, 52)'},
    { label: "my boyfriend",  data: 30, color: 'rgb(125, 141, 62)'},
    { label: "my job",  data: 30, color: '#42215F'},
    { label: "food",  data: 10, color: 'rgb(145, 164, 72)'},
    { label: "social skills",  data: 0, color: 'rgb(166, 189, 82)'}
];

    alert("in chart.js");

    var charttype = "pie";

    var type = {};
    type[charttype] = {show: true};

    var chart_options = {};
    chart_options["series"]=type;

    var plot = $.plot($("#chart1"), data3, chart_options);
}
```

Comment: What does the markup this code generates look like? (View source in browser)

Comment: Seconding the need to show the source - specifically, paste the `show_graph` line that gets generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `series_names` is just being output as the HTML entities of an object without a proper `__unicode__` method. You're getting:

```
show_graph("pie", [&lt;ResponseOption: puddentane&gt;,
```

Which, decoded, is:

```
show_graph("pie", [<ResponseOption: puddentane>, ...
```

What actually needs passing to the method? You probably need to think about how you want `{{ series_names }}` to be output, rather than just calling the string representation of that variable. What you're generating at the moment is invalid Javascript - the console of your browser will probably reinforce this point.

Comment: I will address that issue later, thank you. However, at the moment, I'm not actually using series_names-- I've got the values hardcoded in and it is still not working

Comment: That's irrelevant. Both `[&lt;ResponseOption: puddentane&gt;,` and `[<ResponseOption: puddentane>,` are invalid JavaScript and should not be there. If you're not using them, replace `{{ series_names }}` with `[]`.

Comment: Sam and Mike are the winners: the invalid javascript was preventing the code from running. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Invalid number of parameters means one of your context variables, probably `answer`, was blank.

Your code is risky because Django will escape your context variables to be HTML safe, not JavaScript safe. One trick I use to get around this is to put all the parameters to a JS function in a dictionary, then convert it to JSON and use that for the context variable (using it with the `|safe` filter, and the `<![CDATA[` markup in the template if needed).

As for `show_chart` not being resolved, you might want to make sure `chart.js` really is being loaded, and that it's not in a namespace of some form.

Comment: How would I go about checking to see if chart.js is really being loaded? That may well be the problem here.

Comment: Use debugging tools with your browser. In Firefox, install Firebug and turn it on. In Safari, enable the Developer menu in Preferences. There's a Resources tab or equivalent that shows each thing loaded for the page and any status codes.